# Passing form values on a submit to an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a common case of allowing a user to submit a form with some values and needed to pass those values to my ajax call. This approach works, but is there a more elegant/efficient way of accessing the form values other than using selectors?

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){

myData = {name: $("#name").val(), age: $("#age").val()}

  $.ajax({
    url: "foo.php",
    data: myData, 
    type: get
  });
});

<form id="myForm">
Name: <input type="text"  id="name">
Age: <input type="text" id="age">
</form>
```

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` will serialize all the form objects into an array that you can parse server side, for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was hoping for. I'll give it a go. Any gotchas I should know about?

Comment: `serialize` uses name attributes to produce that array. so to be able to produce same result you need to add name attributes to your form elements. That is the only gotcha i can think of.

Comment: That makes sense. Any reason why this would not work within a submitHandler of a jQuery validate function? e.g, submitHandler: function(){ var test = $(this).serialize; alert(test); } is bringing up null.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, had to pass the form and then reference the form.. E.G submitHandler: function(form){ var test = $(form).serialize; }

Comment: @JasonWells add your own working solution and mark it correct, keep solved questions as "Answered".

Comment: One issue in the context which I am using it (appending the var as a query string to a ajax call), is that select boxes get passed in with nulls if they are not required. Consequently, our query string begins to look like optionBoxValue=&column2=foo. So, I am back to specifying the query string myself.